# Workflow for Sintel Production Files to Unity. Any Ideas?

Tags: animation, rigging, export, .fbx

So, basically what I'm trying to do is export the rigs and animation from the Sintel scene files so that I could use them for retargeting in Unity. I want to use the modern Sintel model made in Blender 3.4 with the animations from the production files made in 2.53. Some of the problems I'm having are:

*Export to FBX converts all the IK points to empties and doesn't export the skeleton.

*2.53 only exports to FBX ASCII, and the Autodesk binary converter spits out a broken file. 2.79 does binary exports though.

*all the linked files are throwing me for a loop.

*Rokoko retargeting plugin isn't working or I matched the bones wrong. I figured it should be automatic since they're the same skeleton.

The end goal is to have an FBX file with the modern rigged Sintel and a bunch of FBX files, one for each action in the movie, each containing just a rig and animation. Same goal for the dragons and other characters. Can anyone suggest the best workflow to achieve this? Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.